# C# How to use FirstOrDefault with an array while unable to have System.Linq in the namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

The code provided here works when I test it in the IDE, but the software itself which will be using this code doesn't give me the possibility declare `using System.Linq`. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to use this else I'll have to go back to a solution I'd rather not use because it has a lower accuracy rate.

The issue is here

```
var stringMatch = sArray.FirstOrDefault(titleID.Contains);
```

I'm not sure how to properly provide the references. I think it should be something along the ways of `System.Linq.Enumerable`... but it's the first time I'm dealing with such an issue so any help much appreciated.

```
        string TakeEndPeriod = "";
        string NewEndPeriod = "";
        string FindEndSpace = "";
        string GetEndPeriod = "";
        string titleID = "document for the period ended December 31 2014";

        string s1 = "ended ";
        string s2 = "Ended ";
        string s3 = "Ending ";
        string[] sArray = new [] { s1, s2, s3};


             var stringMatch = sArray.FirstOrDefault(titleID.Contains);
            if (stringMatch != null)
            {
                TakeEndPeriod = titleID.Substring(titleID.LastIndexOf(stringMatch));
                FindEndSpace = TakeEndPeriod.Substring(TakeEndPeriod.IndexOf(" "));
                GetEndPeriod = FindEndSpace.Substring(1);

               string[] formatArray = new[] { "dd MMMM yyyy", "MMMM dd yyyy" };

                DateTime ModEndPeriod;
                if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(GetEndPeriod,
                                            formatArray,
                                            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                            System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                                            out ModEndPeriod))
                {
                        //parsing failed

                }

                NewEndPeriod = ModEndPeriod.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00Z");
```

**EDIT:**

error message I'm getting:

```
'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension
 method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be
 found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**EDIT:**

This is the solution I got from the dev support managing the software:

```
String Title = "document for the period Ending December 31 2014";
            Match M = Regex.Match(Title, ".*?(?i)(ended|ending)(.*)");//Case insensitive search for "ended" and "ending"
            if (M.Groups.Count == 3)
            {
                //Match OK
                DateTime DT = DateTime.Parse(M.Groups[2].Value);
                //The variable DT will now have the parsed date.
                Console.WriteLine(DT.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
            }
```

Comment: Backtrack....what error are you *actually* getting?

Comment: You should reference System.Core with version >= 3.5. Why this can be a problem?

Comment: Are you asking for an alternative to Linq or a solution to get Linq to work?

Comment: The software using your code should have a .NET Framework version 3.5 or above

Comment: @user2310920 Although the framework version is a likely candidate for it not working, `FirstOrDefault` is quite simple enough for you to implement yourself if you really need to; although that isn't the solution I'd suggest.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "the software itself which will be using this code doesn't give me the possibility declare "using System.Linq""? You need to be much more specific - and explain what software this is...

Comment: @ovm a solution to get Linq to work

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't have access to the namespace declarations. For example when I use a Regex.Replace I need to have System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace. Other example when I try to do ParseExact or similar I need to have the parameter System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture instead of just CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and these work, but when it comes to using .FirstOrDefault with Array or .Any the same approach doesn't work at all.

Comment: @user2310920: What do you mean by "don't have access to"? Again, it would really help if you could explain your context more, as it sounds like it's pretty non-standard.

Comment: It's a web extraction software which has this functionality that enables you to write additional instructions using C# in order to generate metadata to go along with the data being extracted from the source. The compiler is annoying, I don't have access to the namespace declarations as already mentioned and I'm mostly debugging  in an IDE before placing the code in the software to test if it's working properly. This time I figured out something new I haven't tried yet and it seems I'm just bashing my head against a brickwall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> doesn't give me the possibility to declare 'using System.Linq'.

Since `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` is an extension method you can also use it's fully qualified class-name `System.Linq.Enumerable`:

```
var stringMatch = System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(sArray, s => titleID.Contains(s));
```

or even shorter:

```
var stringMatch = System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(sArray, titleID.Contains);
```

Note that an extension method is simply a static method, that's why that works.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Bylejt)</kbd>

Comment: I've tried this and I got: Compiler error "The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @user2310920: i thought that you can use LINQ but you cannot change the `using` part. Which framework are you using? Maybe you could use .NET 3.5 or higher but the project is configured to use a lower version.

Comment: It should be using 3.5 or 4.0 even. When I try to reference System.Core i get the same message as in the first comment here but instead of 'Linq' i see 'Core' which is really weird.

Comment: @user2310920: what means _"it should be"_? What target-framework _is_ it? Have a look at the project's settings (right click, properties). Is the `System.Core` dll added as reference in your project?

Comment: I seem to be conufing you, the compiler messages I'm posting here are from the compiler inside the software. It's licensed and the support guys are responding not so often, I don't have any trouble getting the solution you posted to work in an IDE when not having using System.Linq; in the namespace. Anyways, I'm waiting for a reply from them what could be the reasoning for this. I wanted to ask a question here to know where I'm standing and maybe clear up anything I may be doing wrong. It's a web data extraction software btw.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement `FirstOrDefault` yourself or take it from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/a.html#b7e5965cab68b1cf):

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
     if (source == null) throw ArgumentException("source");
     if (predicate == null) throw ArgumentException("predicate");

     foreach (TSource element in source) 
     {
        if (predicate(element)) 
        return element;
     }

     return default(TSource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to avoid LINQ and use array for a first or default is:

```
Array.Find(array, predicate);
```